# CLOSED - RouterLink doesn't work properly to show user detail - Angular 8

Tags: angular, routes, navigation, angular8, routerlink

I am doing an app and I am having an issue to show the user detail. I think I have added correctly all steps about router but for any unknown reason it is not working.

The idea is that I have a menu with an option that is "Users" which content is a table with the users list. In the id column of the table I have a link with the id of the user and when I click in this link it should go to the user's detail. The url is taking the params fine(localhost:4200/users/{id_of_user}) but the content is not loaded.

Here is my code:

**app.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: SidebarLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { xxx },
      { path: 'users', component: UserListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
          children: [
            { path: ':id', component: UserAccountDetailComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
          ]
      },
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
   .
   .
   .
   imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
   ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**user-list.component.ts**

```
<table class="user-list" mat-table [dataSource]="userListDataSource">
   .
   .
   .
   <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>id</th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">
            <a [routerLink]="['/users', user.id]">
               {{ user.id }}
            </a>
         </td>
   </ng-container>
</table>
```

**user-account-detail.component.ts**

```
export class UserAccountDetailComponent implements OnInit {
   .
   .
   .
   constructor(
       private route: ActivatedRoute
   ) {
    let userId;
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      userId = +params.get('id');
    });
   .
   .
   .
}
```

**sidebar-menu.component.html**

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">
        <a routerLink="/users">Users</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Could anybody help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you get some errors?

Comment: I can't see any `<router-outlet>`s

Comment: @MaSza I don't have errors. In console neither.

Comment: @Eldar the <router-outlet> is in app.component.html. I forgot attach it to the stackoverflow code question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@c_ogoo, @Eldar I found the solution. Thank you so much for your interest and help.

The solution is as follow:

**app.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: SidebarLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { xxx },
      { path: 'merchants/:id', component: MerchantAccountDetailComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'merchants', component: MerchantListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
   .
   .
   .
   imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
   ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**sidebar-menu.component.ts**

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: false }">
        <a routerLink="/users">Users</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your router configuration, you need a `<router-outlet>` in your `UserListComponent`. Any routes defined in the `children` property of your route are rendered inside a nested router outlet.

So your `UserListComponent` becomes:

```html
<table class="user-list" mat-table [dataSource]="userListDataSource">
   .
   .
   .
   <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>id</th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">
            <a [routerLink]="['/users', user.id]">
               {{ user.id }}
            </a>
         </td>
   </ng-container>
</table>

<!-- This is where your UserAccountDetailComponent will render -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Your SideBar component also needs a router outlet:

```html
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">
        <a routerLink="/users">Users</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Edit:**

Or if you want to use just the one `router-outlet` you should change your router config to:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: SidebarLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { xxx },
      { path: 'users', component: UserListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
      { path: 'users/:id', component: UserAccountDetailComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    ]
  },
];
```

Comment: Thank you for you response @c_ogoo. The <router-outlet> is in app.component.html. I forgot attach it to the stackoverflow code question. Your help is still not working.

Comment: you need a second `<router-outlet>` in your `UserListComponent` template

Comment: @BeatrizIC if a route defines a children property parent route's component should define a router outlet so `SidebarLayoutComponent` and `UserListComponent` have to have a router outlet in their view

Comment: @Eldar I have added the router-outlet to both components and still not works. I noticed that doesn't access to the service to get the user details and it is in the ngOnInit method of the component but is having the user id.

Comment: Then maybe your AuthGuard is blocking it?

Comment: @c_ogoo no. The AuthGuard is working fine. I've removed and that is not the problem.

Comment: Please replicate on stackblitz